# Magento doesn't save product in database

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.7

my Magento 1.7.0.2 doesn't save product in database. After entering of datas and confirmation end it whitout error but product doesn't appear in catalog and in database. In system.log I have this:

```
2014-04-16T00:51:31+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3645
```

and in exception.log I have this:

```
2014-04-16T00:50:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'website_date' in 'field list'
Trace: #0 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1974): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1947): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#7 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(599): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertMultiple('catalog_product...', Array)
#8 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(378): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->_prepareWebsiteDateTable()
#9 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(178): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
#14 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
#15 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /data/web/virtuals/45559/virtual/www/subdom/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Could anyone advise me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alda ,`website_date` column has been missing from `catalog_product_index_website` table.Check that table.

Table sql is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_index_website` (
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID',
  `website_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Date',
  `rate` float DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Rate',
  PRIMARY KEY (`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_DATE` (`website_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Website Index Table';
```